# How to increase the jQuery Sortable performance for IE8?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery sortable for make the "1000 items" list sortable, and i need to support IE8.

The performance is really very bad. So, is there is anyway to increase the performance ?

or, can anyone tell the reason why it is slow ?

I have check on chrome performance is good.

```
$('#list').sortable();
```

Comment: jQuery and jQuery UI version? Are you using connectWith option?

Comment: jQuery v1.10.2    ;    jQuery UI - v1.10.3   , No i am not using any options.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the JQuery Sortable performance issue, I have created my own plugin for Drag&Drop and it supports all the browser and even performance is very good.

Please have a look and share your feedback

Link : [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/yKxj5/)

```
//Default Options ------------------------------------- 
  items: null, // Items which are draggable
  container: null, // Container of the Items
  placeHolder: "clone",
  helper: "clone",
  helperX: 15, // Helper message position from mouse-pointer
  helperY: 20, // Helper message position from mouse-pointer
  scrollSpeed: 10,
  scrollDelay: 10, 
  scrollPointTop: 20,  
  scrollPointBottom: 20,
  onDragStart: null,  //Function Call
  onDrag: null,  //Function Call
  onDrop: null   //Function Call
```